# I am getting this error can someone please help me

Tags: python

```
    for word in text.split():    
      if word in user_greeting:    
        return random.choice(bots_greetings)
```

```
    File "<ipython-input-31-849d4fc18850>", line 9
        return random.choice(bots_greetings)
        ^
    SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Comment: please add your sample text and user response

Comment: What's not clear about the error? You are using `return` outside of a function. Do you know what `return` is used for?

Comment: what are you expecting from the `return` statement here?

Answer (score 2):

The error says it, your return should be inside the function scope. and not outside.

```
# this will cause an error
def foo():
return 

# this will not
def foo():
    return
```

Comment: But the `return` is indented in the original code...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `return` outside a function. It is used to return something **from a *function*.** To print something, use the `print(value)` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your indentation of the return statement, to make sure it is indented in side of the function.